# Hecke eigenvalue at p and at p^k

Tags: nt.number-theory, hecke-algebras, automorphic-forms, modular-forms

I am interested in the relationship between the Hecke eigenvalue at $p$ and at $p^k$ for $k \geq 2$ in the unramified and ramified situation for modular/Maass forms.

More precisely, I know from a representation theoretic perspective that the Hecke eigenvalue at $p$ determines uniquely the factor of the automorphic representation at $p$, and consequently should determine the Hecke eigenvalue at $p^k$. Are there formulas, which express this quantitatively, i.e., does there exist a polynomial $P_k$ such that
$$ \lambda( p^k)  = P_k( \lambda(p) )?$$

Comment: You need to know the eigenvalue for "$S_p$" too: this would typically be (depending on normalisations) something like $p^{n-1}\chi(p)$ with $\chi$ the character of the modular/Maass form (i.e if the form has non-trivial character and $n$ the weight (you used $k$ in the question so I can't!), then you see this in the formula. And then indeed there's a polynomial $P_k(X,Y)$ depending only on $k$ such that if you let $X$ be the $T_p$-eigenvalue and $Y$ the $S_p$-eigenvalue then it spits out the $T_{p^k}$-eigenvalue. To see such a formula open any book on modular forms!

Comment: PS your representation-theoretic argument doesn't quite give what you say it gives: the Hecke algebra is the subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,X^{-1},Y^{-1}]$ fixed by the Weyl group (which switches $X$ and $Y$) so it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[T,S,S^{-1}]$ with $T=X+Y$ and $S=XY$. Hence the need for the two pieces of data. And then you can only see that it's a poly in $T$, $S$ and $S^{-1}$. The fact that $S^{-1}$ is not needed is I guess just a coincidence which comes out of the explicit calculation.

Comment: I added a handy reference to the response that you already accepted (thanks!). Please read the response again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each $k$ there is such a polynomial and can be determined recursively from the usual relation $\lambda(m)\lambda(n)=\sum_{d\mid (m,n)}\chi(d)\lambda(mn/d^2)$, where $\chi$ is the nebentypus (for weight zero Maass newforms). Am I missing something?

Actually, for unramified primes $P_k(x)=U_k(x/2)$, where $U_k$ is the $k$-th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, while for ramified primes $P_k(x)=x^k$. See Section 2.3 in [Young's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4042).

Comment: Thanks! $\chi$ must be primitive Nebentypus according to the level?

Comment: Even better! Thx a lot for the help!

Comment: Dear Marc: $\chi$ is an arbitrary Dirichlet character modulo the level (e.g. there are newforms for trivial nebentypus). If $\chi$ happens to be primitive modulo the level, then there are no oldforms for that level, which is useful in some calculations. The nebentypus is just the classical version of the central character.

Comment: Btw. $U_k$ is related to the character of irr.reps. of $SU(2)$. The Sato-Tate measure also originates from $SU(2)$:)